# How to compile a Makefile plugin?

Tags: plugins, makefile, gnu

I was trying to compile the plugin example given in the Makefile documentation(https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <gnumake.h>

int plugin_is_GPL_compatible;

char *
gen_tmpfile(const char *nm, int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fd;

  /* Compute the size of the filename and allocate space for it.  */
  int len = strlen (argv[0]) + 6 + 1;
  char *buf = gmk_alloc (len);

  strcpy (buf, argv[0]);
  strcat (buf, "XXXXXX");

  fd = mkstemp(buf);
  if (fd >= 0)
    {
      /* Don't leak the file descriptor.  */
      close (fd);
      return buf;
    }

  /* Failure.  */
  fprintf (stderr, "mkstemp(%s) failed: %s\n", buf, strerror (errno));
  gmk_free (buf);
  return NULL;
}

int
mk_temp_gmk_setup ()
{
  /* Register the function with make name "mk-temp".  */
  gmk_add_function ("mk-temp", gen_tmpfile, 1, 1, 1);
  return 1;
}
```

but when running the following line: gcc -c mk_temp.c -fPIC,
I get the following error message:

> mk_temp.c:8:21: fatal error: gnumake.h: No such file or directory

I couldn't find this file in my computer. I even downloaded the Makefile 3.8.1 (the same Makefile version I have installed) sources but is not there neither.

Anyone knows how to get this file or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Andrés.

Comment: Did you ever successfully load the object? If so, can you please share your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v3.81 is too old. `gnumake.h` appears in GNU make 4.0

Comment: To be absolutely clear, `3.8.1` isn't even a valid GNU make version.  You mean `3.81`, not `3.8.1`.

Comment: @MadScientist Indeed. Fixed.